# while min value of supplier table not able to give name to subquery

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Im trying to get the price from a supplier list into a join with the table.
But I am not able to give the Subquery a Name/shorthandel (A in this case)

I get the following message

```
Meldung 8155, Ebene 16, Status 2, Zeile 16
No columnname 1 was given to the column L'
```

This is my query

```
SELECT [kItem]
  ,[ItemID] as ebayID
  ,[SKU]
  ,A.[cArtNr]
  ,[StartPrice]
  ,[Title]
  ,I.[kArtikel]
  ,[Status]
  ,A.fVKNetto
  ,A.fVKBrutto
  ,L.fEKBrutto
  ,L.fEKNetto
  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[ebay_item] I
  JOIN [dbname].[dbo].[tartikel] A ON A.[kArtikel] = I.[kArtikel]
  left JOIN (Select min(fEKNetto),[tArtikel_kArtikel]  
  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tliefartikel] L Group by fEKNetto, [tArtikel_kArtikel])
  AS L  ON L.[tArtikel_kArtikel] = I.[kArtikel]
```

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense.  You are grouping on `fEKNetto` and doing the `min(fEKNetto)` in the same subquery.  This is allowed, but generally nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the alias on the subquery.  It is the column `min(fEKNetto)`.  Give that an alias, which based on the rest of the code should be `fEKNetto`.  I think this is the subquery you want:

```
FROM [dbname].[dbo].[ebay_item] I JOIN
     [dbname].[dbo].[tartikel] A
     ON A.[kArtikel] = I.[kArtikel] left JOIN
     (Select min(fEKNetto) as fEKNetto, [tArtikel_kArtikel]  
      FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tliefartikel] L
      Group by [tArtikel_kArtikel])
     ) L
     ON L.[tArtikel_kArtikel] = I.[kArtikel]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [kItem]
      ,[ItemID] as ebayID
      ,[SKU]
      ,A.[cArtNr]
      ,[StartPrice]
      ,[Title]
      ,I.[kArtikel]
      ,[Status]
      ,A.fVKNetto
      ,A.fVKBrutto
      ,L.fEKBrutto
      ,L.fEKNetto
FROM [dbname].[dbo].[ebay_item] I
JOIN [dbname].[dbo].[tartikel] A ON A.[kArtikel] = I.[kArtikel]
left JOIN (Select min(fEKNetto) AS fEKNetto  --<-- This Alias was missing
                ,[tArtikel_kArtikel]  
           FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tliefartikel]  
           Group by [tArtikel_kArtikel]  --<-- only group by  tArtikel_kArtikel
           )AS L  
ON L.[tArtikel_kArtikel] = I.[kArtikel]
```